# My conditional statement isn't working

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am in an entry level visual basic class. I am trying to test user input to see if it us numeric using the IsNumeric boolean function. Basically, if the input is not numeric, I want it to throw up a messagebox saying so, and if it IS numeric, I want it to set the numeric values as variables. Every time I enter a non-numeric value, I don't get the messagebox, instead I get an exception when it tries to convert a non-numeric string to a double using CDbl. What am I doing wrong?

```
    If txtInches.Text = "" Or txtFeet.Text = "" Then 'Checks to ensure height fields were not left blank
        'If fields were blank, throws error message up, changes textbox backgroud color to red, focuses user on error and exits sub.
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for both feet and inches. Don't leave these fields blank, and try again.", "Height Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        txtFeet.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtInches.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtFeet.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then 'Checks to see if age field was blank
        'If age field was blank, throws error message up, changes textbox backgroud color to red, focuses user on error and exits sub.
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter your age. Don't leave this field blank, and try again.", "Age Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        txtFeet.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtInches.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtFeet.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(dblFeet) Then
        'If feet input is not numeric, throws error message up, changes textbox background color to red, focuses user on error and exits sub.
        MessageBox.Show("Feet must be a numeric value. Please try again.", "Height Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        txtFeet.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtFeet.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(dblInches) Then 'Checks to see if height input is numeric
        'If inches input is not numeric, throws error message up, changes textbox background color to red, focuses user on error and exits sub.
        MessageBox.Show("Inches must be a numeric value. Please try again.", "Height Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        txtInches.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtInches.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(dblAge) Then 'Checks to see if age input is numeric
        'If age input is not numeric, throws error message up, changes textbox background color to red, focuses user on error and exits sub.
        MessageBox.Show("Your age must be a number. Please try again.", "Age Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        txtAge.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtAge.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        dblFeet = CDbl(txtFeet.Text)
        dblInches = CDbl(txtInches.Text)
        dblAge = CDbl(txtAge.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: There is no need to test **and** convert if you use `Double.TryParse()` - it will do both

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out. I was testing the dblVariable when I should have been testing the txtVariable.text. Facepalm.

Comment: Thats the problem with those old fashioned VB functions - they almost all take `Object` param arguments so you can pass anything and make mistakes like that

Comment: Thanks for all the info @plutonix, I really appriciate it. We are being taught to use CSng, CInt, etc. Sounds like this is depricated though (as is my professor in most respects).

Comment: It/they are not deprecated *officially* just by general consensus, the various Parse methods are a bit more robust and if you get in the habit of not using the legacy methods, switching to c# is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in an education, not just a grade, here is a more succinct way using NET methods:

```
' assumes all the values are form/class 
' leval variables
Private nAge As Int32
```

Then for the validation:

```
    ' if it parses, then nAge will have the value
    If Integer.TryParse(tbAge.Text, nAge) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer for Age", 
                          "Annoying MsgBox", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Return
    End If
```

- I dint know why you are using doubles - do you really expect `"5.8"` feet or an input `"28.7"` for age?
- Using `Integer.TryParse` you can perform just one test: it will detect/fail on empty strings as well as `"I like pie"`
- Rather than tell them one error at a time, you could accumulate the bad elements and tell them everything that is wrong.  The `ErrorProvider` is good for this.

One of the problems with the old VB functions is that almost everything is `As Object`.  This allows you to do something like `IsNumeric(dblAge)` which will always be true.  The NET methods are more strongly typed, so that you can only pass a string.